# Ajax call within a 'for' loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to using ajax call in a loop?
Here I want, when I single click on button then the ajax call will called 10 times. below is my code. Don't know is it good practice or not.

But I need this type of solution. How can I do it? thank you.

HTML:

```
  <button>Click</button>
```

AJAX :

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
            $('button').click(function(){
                  for(var i=1;i<=10;i++){        //is it possible ?
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url : "a.php",
                        data:'a='+$('.div1').text(),
                        success: function(result){
                                $('.div1').html(result);
                            }                               
                    });
                  }
                });
        });
```

a.php :

```
        <?php
             if(!isset($_POST['a']) || $_POST['a'] == ""){
                $a = 0;
             }
             else{
                $a = $_POST['a'] + 1;   
             }
             echo $a;
             exit();
         ?>
```

Comment: It is. Why do you need it? What are you going to handle at server side?

Comment: What is your problem with your current code?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You're calling the same thing over and over. Are you sure you don't want to run a `$('.div1').each()` with AJAX inside it? Still, you could just `Array.join()` the `.text()` from `$('.div1').each()` and send once to the Server with AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        var ajaxCalled=0;
        $('button').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    url : "a.php",
                    data:'a='+$('.div1').text(),
                    success: function(result){
                            $('.div1').html(result);
                            ajaxCalled++;
                            if(ajaxCalled<=10){
                                $('button').trigger('click');
                            }
                            else{
                                ajaxCalled=0;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }               
                });
            });
    });
```

Comment: you're welcome, please accept the answer by clicking the check-mark beside my answer, if this answer is in fact what you were looking for. ;)

Comment: is it OK to run 1000 times like this?

Comment: Do you mean in a loop?